# invoke a java project from jsp button click event

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans

I have created a simple java project to draw the bar chart taking certain values from text file and named it as `ChartAdvancedBar.java`, now i need to invoke it when I press a button in JSP file.

I have added this java project within the libraries of my web project. How can I import this java project to one of my JSP files?

I have added a line:

```
<%@page import="ChartAdvancedBar.*"%>
```

But it is giving an error that `ChartAdvancedBar` doesn't found.

Comment: <%@page import="ChartAdvancedBar.*"%> this line i hav added

Comment: Where is the package name? It should be packagename.ChartAdvancedBar

Comment: And how are you invoking the java class? Can you explain a bit on that ?

Comment: One advice **do not use scriptlets `<% %>` in JSP.** See [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1031945)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<jsp:useBean id="give id here like an object" class="Fully qualified name of class file">
```

tag then access method

Make sure it should be compiled before using this.